# What is the return type of ternary operator applied to 'const char* const&' and 'char* &'?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, conditional-operator

Consider the following useless code snippet, which gives inconsistent results with different compilers ([demo](https://godbolt.org/z/TW16a1Kbh))

```
#include <type_traits>

char* dummy;
const char* const& a = dummy;
      char*      & b = dummy;
using T = decltype(true ? a : b);
static_assert(std::is_same<const char* const&, T>::value); // pass in Clang and MSVC:c++20
static_assert(std::is_same<const char*       , T>::value); // pass in GCC   and MSVC:c++17
```

GCC considers `T` to be `const char*` in all versions of C++, while Clang considers it to be `const char* const&` in all versions; MSVC considers `T` to be `const char*` under C++17 and `const char* const&` under C++20.

From a language lawyer’s perspective,  which compiler should I trust?

Comment: Is [expr.cond#4.1](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.cond#4.1) any help? _If E2 is an lvalue, the target type is “lvalue reference to T2”, but an implicit conversion sequence can only be formed if the reference would bind directly ([dcl.init.ref]) to a glvalue_.  If not, then we end up with an rvalue.  I think that makes Clang correct.

Comment: Note: MSVC with `/std:c++17` and `/permissive-` also considers `T` to be `const char* const&`.

Comment: MSVC C++ for C++17 defaults to "C++ with Microsoft extensions" (unless `/premissive-` is used to disable Microsoft extensions), but C++20 defaults to standards compliant C++.  Which is somewhat analagous to `clang++` being in `--std=gnu++17`, versus `--std=c++17`.